# Changing LastName,FirstName to LastName,FirstInitial

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm sure this is super easy, but how would I go about converting LastName,FirstName to LastName,FirstInitial?

For example changing Smith,John to Smith,J or Johnson,John to Johnson,J etc.

Thank You!

Comment: what you are tried?

Answer (score 2):

In case of LastName and FirstName columns:

```
select  LastName,substr(FirstName,1,1) 
from    mytable
;
```

In case of a fullname saved in a single column:

```
select  substr(fullname,1,instr(fullname || ',',',')-1) || substr(fullname,instr(fullname || ',',','),2) 
from    mytable
;
```

or

```
select  regexp_replace (fullname,'([^,]*,?)(.).*','\1\2')
from    mytable
;
```

Comment: Thanks, this was super helpful!

Comment: You're welcome. Please check the last version (second option). It will protect you in case there is no comma in the full name

Comment: @Mitch Don't forget to accept this answer if you're satisfied with it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way, using just "standard" `instr` and `substr`. Assuming your input is a single string in the format `'Smith,John'`:

```
select substr(fullname, 1, instr(fullname, ',')+1) from yourtable;
```

`yourtable` is the name of the table, and `fullname` is the name of the column.

`instr(fullname, ',') finds the position of the comma within the input string (it would be 6 in 'Smith,John'); then`substr`takes the substring that begins at the first position (the`1`in the function call) and ends at the position calculated by`instr`, PLUS 1 (to get the first initial as well).